# Unity Facebook SDK: excludeIds/filters not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

I am making a new games, so i wanna use API 2.0, But i got a question in "AppRequest"

The filters/excludeIds field seems not work when popping the dialog up.

I found that : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Apprequest/

This list is currently not supported for mobile devices, but i want to reward player when they invite some friends, So how can i do in v2.0 ? or I need fallback to v1.0 ?

But i tried use Graph API Explorer query "me/friends?fields=installed" it's only return "installed": true

How can i do a "normal flow" of invitetion, Thanks.